# Django error happened when I installed debug toolbar

Tags: django

everything was working perfectly before until i installed debug toolbar
everything was working perfectly befor until i installed django debug toolbar I don’t understand why it is now saying this in the terminal

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add some code here

Comment: Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leo/Documents/storefront/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "/home/leo/Documents/storefront/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 16, in cached_import
    return getattr(module, class_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.middleware.csrf' has no attribute 'CsrfVpziewMiddleware'. Did you mean: 'CsrfViewMiddleware'?

Comment: The error is more than this but I can’t post it because it is too long

Comment: This is the full error code https://gist.github.com/balogun14/c8d28d640bf9381d9d442505129adc4e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you posted, there is something with middleware.

You must be using `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfVpziewMiddleware` in your middleware which should be `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`. Please replace `CsrfVpziewMiddleware` with `CsrfViewMiddleware` and your error will be fixed.